# MutationObserver: Mirror DOM mutations to virtual DOM

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have to implement somehow the subject. My idea is simply add special attribute to the real nodes mapping to the corresponding virtual ones. However for some reason I have issues with huge enough web apps. For example, I've found out sometimes there is sequence of mutations where firstly the parent element remove and then child is removed (so I have exception).

Maybe there is some open source library for this (mutation-summary is abounded and doesn't work really good in my case)? Or maybe there is another simple solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably know this, but this does not seem like something that should be happening. Why is something mutating the dom without the vdom knowing?

Comment: @SamH, Seems like Angular has some MutationObservers inside its core and use it to update the real dom.

Comment: Ahh sorry Ximik